# Google Analytics recognize transaction ID but not products

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I have a huge problem with my Google Analytics e-commerce part.

This is my JavaScript code on website:

```
    ga("create", "UA-93459727-1", { name: "checkout" });
    ga('checkout.require', 'ec');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    ga('checkout.ec:addProduct',
       {
           "id": "4361018360",
           "name": "C3 PRO",
           "brand": "Semniti",
           "variant": "Glossy White",
           "dimension1": "63",
           "price" : "444.69",
           "quantity" : "1"
        });
    ga('checkout.ec:setAction', 'add');
    ga('checkout.ec:setAction','checkout', {
        'step': 6
    });

    ga('checkout.ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
        'id': 80135606039228800
    });

    ga('checkout.send', 'pageview');
```

This code in my Google Analytics gives this result:

[image: Google Analytics transactions]

He **recognizes transaction** but he **don't recognize products**.

Google Tag Manager debugger (tab Analytics):
[image]

Google Analytics debugger:
[image]

I tried this on 2 ways. 
First was when I add all products on step 1, and purchase/transaction id on last step 6.
Second was when I add all information's on step 6.
On both way, results were same.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are sending 2 events: add [to cart] and purchase. As you are sending "add to cart" action before "purchase", the product is attributed to the first action rather than to purchase itself.